# mysql restore from dump backup of all databases with user privileges

Tags: permissions, mysql, backup

I have read so many tutorials and tried so many things.

I have a single sql file of all databases backed up with mysqldump (50+).

When I try to restore the databases using root account - they restore just fine, but the users with privileges are not seemed to be carried over.

I can't manually create each user as there are over 50 databases and I don't know the password of each and who owns what database or what the user privileges are for each database.

I have read countless tutorials on this subject but cannot find the proper way to restore from dump WITH user passwords and privileges. It seems after importing there are no users except root as owner. If I flush privileges then root has no access to the databases at all and cannot access mysql from command line.

I am totally baffled at how this is done.

The only commands I can find is

```
mysql -u root < db_backup.sql
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p < db_backup.sql
```

Neither of these options seem to carry over users, passwords, and privileges

When I did the backup it was a simple:

```
mysqldump -u root –all-databases > db_backup.sql
```

Did I do something wrong when backing up that didn't carry username, passwords and privileges or am I doing something wrong during restore?

*** UPDATE ***

If I issue:

```
show databases;
```

all the databases are displayed.

If I issue:

```
select user from mysql.user;
```

all the users are displayed.

However none of the users are able to access any of the databases.

Comment: Did you flush privileges? Cuz that is mandatory after updating the mysql database.

Comment: I have no idea why but when I flushed privaleges suddenly root had no access to mysql commands, I did sort it with the help from the datacenter - they told me instead of flushing, to just restart mysql, which seemed to work perfectly - so its likely I was flushing the databases wrong.

Comment: If you can answer this with the proper way to flush 50+ databases at the same time I will mark it correct.

Comment: what do you mean "flush 50 databases"? You flush *privileges*. Has nothing to do with databases; it is connected to how mysql keeps track of permissions in memory; flushing those drops the active privileges and reloads the GRANTs you have stored.

Comment: when I tried 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' it returned error 'You have made an error in your SQL syntax;'

Comment: Then you made a typo ;) Like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-privileges